# iif statement returning the wrong results

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using these expressions to group my data in columns

```
=CountDistinct(iif((Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value >= DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1")
AND Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value <= DateSerial(Year(Now()), 
Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)), 1,0))
=CountDistinct(iif((Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value >= DateSerial(Year(Now()),
Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(1) AND Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value <= 
DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)), 1,0))
=CountDistinct(iif((Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value >= DateSerial(Year(Now()),
Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(2) AND Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value <= 
DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(3).AddDays(-1)), 1,0))
=CountDistinct(iif((Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value >= DateSerial(Year(Now()), 
Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(3) AND Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value <= 
DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(4).AddDays(-1)), 1,0))
```

Here is the outcome

[image]

Here is the data returned from the query

[image]

As you can see the April and May fields are showing 1 result returned, when I believe it should show 0. The `No COE(I_Sch_Close) Column` should be 11 but reads 2 with the following expression:

```
=CountDistinct(iif(ISNOTHING(Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value),1,0))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IIf statement in the following expression for No COE returns 1 or 0

```
=CountDistinct(iif(ISNOTHING(Fields!I_Sch_Close.Value),1,0))
```

The distinct count of those can't be more than 2. Instead, you need to count occurrences where your expression is True. Try something like this:

```
=Count(IIf(<expression>, 1, Nothing))
```